# How do you output the ACTUAL filesystem type on a Linux terminal, based on the mountpoint?

Tags: linux, terminal, filesystems, mount

I thought that I had the right command:

```
findmnt -no FSTYPE -T /media/a/abc123
```

Sadly, it does not output "NTFS" as expected and desired, but instead just returns `fuseblk`

What filesystem type is a "fuseblk"? I can't even figure it out when searching. Either way, it's NTFS. I know that for sure. I want to know if it's NTFS or ext4, for example. On the command line.

I did find this:

```
lsblk -no name,fstype /dev/sde1
```

It outputs almost what I wanted: `sde1 ntfs`

However, it requires me to specify the "device path", which is unknown. I only have the mount point.

How is it done properly, so that only "NTFS" (or "ntfs") is returned, and I only have to give it the mount point (such as `/media/a/abc123`)?

Comment: `mount` should show you all mounts  and I believe their filesystems. If you are looking for physical devices that are mounted, try `mount | grep ^dev`.  If you want to map mounts to their devices, use `df`

Comment: and don't use FUSE NTFS (ntfs-3g), [it's far worse than the kernel NTFS driver (ntfs3)](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/kernel-5-15-ntfs3-vs-ntfs-3g-4175702945/)

Comment: If FUSE is used, this *is* the real filesystem, as far as the kernel is concerned. `findmnt` appears to look no further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ lsblk -lpno name,fstype,MOUNTPOINT | grep boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1 vfat   /boot/efi
```

*(for `/` use `/$` in place of boot)*

Comment: Thank you. Not super "clean", but it never is as clean as I desire... One thing to watch out for is that you need to make sure to use a `$` in the end of the grep, and use the full mountpoint, or else it will falsely report "vfat" instead of "ext4" for "/" or "/boot". My tests now seem to work, but due to the messy output that is grepped, I'm worried that it may grep the wrong values sometimes.

Comment: As always, string matching has to be specific enough to catch only those items you're interested in. Matching a single character (e.g. `/`) will always be troublesome.

Comment: `$ lsblk -lpno name,fstype,MOUNTPOINT | grep boot | cut -d' ' -f2` ->  `vfat` (alone)

Comment: `grep` is prone to error because there can be multiple lines with the pattern, especially for `/`. And `lsblk` already has the ability to output the fstype, no need to `cut`

Comment: Yes? What new info do you mean that your comment brought in?

Answer (score 1):

The reliable way is to use `findmnt` to get the device then list the FSTYPE with `lsblk`

```sh
lsblk -lpno fstype "$(findmnt -no SOURCE /boot)"
lsblk -lpno fstype "$(findmnt -no SOURCE /)"

lsblk -lpno fstype "/dev/disk/by-partuuid/$(findmnt -no PARTUUID /boot)"
lsblk -lpno fstype "/dev/disk/by-partuuid/$(findmnt -no PARTUUID /)"

lsblk -lpno fstype "/dev/disk/by-uuid/$(findmnt -no UUID /boot)"
lsblk -lpno fstype "/dev/disk/by-uuid/$(findmnt -no UUID /)"
```

No need to grep at all