# Create a folder with a name ending with a dot on a NTFS volume in Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, ntfs

On Windows, the win32 API seemingly disallows a directory name to end in a dot (`.`) but according to several questions asked in that direction (e.g. [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4123152), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4075753)), the solution on windows is to specify the path with prefixed with `\\?\` in order to disable string parsing on the API side.
With this, the creation of a directory like `\\?\C:\dotatend.` would be possible (same applies for its deletion).

As I would like to recreate folders ending with a dot on a mounted NTFS-volume (mountpoint `/mnt/myntfsvol`), I wonder how to do so using linux.

My linux system runs kernel 6.7 and mount lists `fuseblk` being used on that mountpoint which doesn't say much about the underlying FS used, but running `lsblk -lpno fstype "$(findmnt -no SOURCE /mnt/myntfsvol)"` (credits to [phuclv](https://superuser.com/a/1798418) for this nested command sequence) confirms the FS to be `ntfs`.

When I try to create a new directory `dotatend.` at the mountpoint using

```
mkdir '/mnt/myntfsvol/dotatend.'
```

, I receive

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/myntfsvol/dotatend.’: Invalid argument
```

The prefix `\\?\` obviously doesn't work and also changing to forward slashes (`//?/`) won't create that directory at the targeted location. The manpage of `mkdir` also doesn't mention anything of some kind of special raw-string-prefixed or similar but my guess is that this would probably need to be addressed on driver level anyway.

Any other ideas hints on how to create a directory ending in a dot on a NFTS filesystem?
Is there any kind of counterpart to the `\\?\` prefix available on linux?

Comment: In Ubuntu WSL I have no problem with `mkdir 'abc.'`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any kind of counterpart to the `\\?\` prefix available on linux?

There isn't, because the entire concept behind it practically doesn't exist on Linux.

This prefix on Windows indicates to the Win32 layer that it should skip all "DOS-like" transformations and pass the raw path directly to the NT kernel. But this is already what happens on Linux – not only is there no intermediate layer that would forbid trailing dots, there is practically no intermediate layer *in general.*

(In Windows terminology, all programs on Linux work directly with the "Native API" and that's the only API that exists – libc is practically ntdll.)

The `Invalid argument` error isn't returned by any intermediate layer; it's actually returned by the Linux [NTFS driver](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/ntfs3/fsntfs.c#n2564). There are two, called "ntfs3" and "ntfs-3g", and both provide the same `windows_names` option to block creation of file names that would be generally considered invalid by Win32.

To find out which driver is in use, you need to look directly at the `findmnt` output, not at the lsblk output. The latter only reports the filesystem type according to device contents, so it will always report "ntfs", whereas the same FSTYPE column in findmnt will show the driver name being used:

| FSTYPE | driver |
| --- | --- |
| `ntfs3` | In-kernel ntfs3 driver |
| `fuseblk` | External NTFS-3G driver (`mount -t ntfs-3g`) |
| `ntfs` | Most likely, the *ancient* in-kernel ntfs driver; avoid it |

Alongside that, you'll also see the OPTIONS column. Make sure it does not list 'windows_names'. If the option is there, unmount the filesystem and mount it again.

Comment: `windows_names` is not being mentioned among the mount options for me but still the creation of a foldername ending in a dot fails for my `fuseblk` automounted NTFS volume.

Comment: `udisksctl (un)mount --block-device /dev/$device` ?

Answer (score 0):

[u1686_grawity's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1833699/116485) pointed me into the right direction but as commented there, even when `windows_names` is **not** among the mount-options in use, `mkdir '/mnt/myntfsvol/dotatend.'` still fails as described in my question.

However, when mounting the volume manually (=not through the *gnome-disk-utility* as I did before) but with the same options `findmnt` is displaying (but still letting the system choose the driver resulting again in `fuseblk`, the creation of folders ending in a dot **works** all of a sudden!

```
sudo mount -o rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,default_permissions /dev/sdb1 /mnt/myntfsvol
```

When explicitly using *ntfs3* through specifying `-t ntfs3`, some options need to be changed as they are not available or named differently but even then,  `mkdir '/mnt/myntfsvol/dotatend.'` works, too.

This is the command I believe should be about equivalent to the ones used with  *fuseblk* above and that I used:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs3 -o rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=0,gid=0 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/myntfsvol
```

It still remains mysterious to me why the behavior is different when using the automount functionality or assistants like *gnome-disk-utility* but at least folders ending in a dot can be created on a NTFS volume.

Comment: If it's auto mounted via udisks2 (i.e. via GNOME), then the option is set by default in `/etc/udisks2/` even if FUSE doesn't seem to report it back.